# Adjust spacing around paragraph (within a div) so that the space on either side is always equal between divs on the right and left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three divs, aligned on a single row as columns, using a `flex` container.

The first and third columns have a small amount of text in each, the middle column has a large paragraph.

What I would like to do is to align the text in the middle div so that the space around between it and the first and third divs is always equal, even when the width of the page changes and the words wrap to the next line.

By default, the word wrapping behaviour means that you can end up with a lot of whitespace on the right of the div, which isn't equal to the whitespace on the left (because of the varying length of words). How do I ensure the spacing adjusts based on the longest word (I assume the longest word), so it it always equal?

Here is some example code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="column1">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <p>
      There is more content in this div than the other divs. Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah...
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column3">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you expand and shrink the window, you can see that as the middle column's words get closer to wrapping, the spacing isn't equal on either side of the div; there is less space on the right than the left. This what I would like to resolve, so the spacing is always equal between the divs.

Comment: Please Gigabit, show some code: [reprex]

Comment: @RenevanderLende, I have added code as requested.

Comment: Adding `.column2 p { text-align: center }` to your CSS would do the trick...

Comment: @RenevanderLende that did not resolve the issue, the whitespace is not even. Also, I do not want the text to be centre aligned, I'd still like it left aligned.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed already that it was too good to be true (hardly ever is). You want the text centered, but not `align center`. `justify-content: space-between` will not solve the problem (all of the time).

Answer (score 2):

There is no completely satisfying solution for what you describe. `justify-content: space-between` on the container is the closest you will get. Or you use `justify-content: space-around` - maybe that's closer to what you are aiming at (hard to tell from your description...):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="column1">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <p>
      There is more content in this div than the other divs. Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah...
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column3">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please run the code snippet to see if this is your desire output.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="column1">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <p>
      There is more content in this div than the other divs. Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah...
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column3">
    <p>
      Some content
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice little trick, @Gigabit I'd go for this one. Maybe adjust the CSS to `.column2 p { text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word }` for the center column only. Add some left/right padding and you're done! Cudos @yinsweet, I'll have to remember this!

Comment: Awhnnn, currently no more than **7.82%** browser support [caniuse text-justify](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-justify)....

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may put a determinated size to the div anthe then a text align for the larga

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: more info how this works https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content